# Java JFrame Form

Tags: java, jframe

I'm try to implement my program by using JFrame Form on Netbean.
Then when i use my main frame to popup other frame and i close that frame, my main frame will close too.
How can i avoid this case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your second popup frame has the default close operation "`EXIT_ON_CLOSE`". This exits the whole program.
So, you have to set this to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`. That will close only the frame you clicked the close button.

In code this will be:

```
your_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

In Netbeans, you have to go to the frame editor modus. Select your frame, and change that property in in the propery-window. You can access it by a right-click on the frame and than "Properties".

Hope this helps.